# How can I make hierarchical columns based on unique values in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas data frame which looks like below:

**S.No**     **Name1**     **Name2**     **Size**

1              ABC           XYZ            12

2              BCA           XCZ            15

3              DAB            ZXM            20

How do I make a hierarcial column for all unique values in Name1 column, followed by column with all unique values in Name2 , which would make the dataframe look like below:

ABC                              BCA                       DAB

S.NO
            XYZ  XCZ  ZXM      
XYZ  XCZ  ZXM      
XYZ  XCZ  ZXM

1                    12     N/A    N/A

2                                                     N/A    15     N/A

3                                                                                       N/A    N/A    20

Answer (score 0):

Consider filling in empty rows with a `merge` on a helper dataframe which is created from unique cartesian product of values (all possible combinations of *S.No*, *Name1*, *Name2*) using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from io import StringIO
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

txt = '''S.No    Name1     Name2     Size    
1           ABC         XYZ         12    
2           BCA         XCZ         15    
3           DAB         ZXM         20'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

fill_df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['S.No'].unique(), df['Name1'].unique(), df['Name2'].unique())), 
                                    columns=['S.No', 'Name1', 'Name2'])

df = df.merge(fill_df, on=['S.No', 'Name1', 'Name2'], how='right')

pvtdf = df.pivot_table(index='S.No', columns=['Name1', 'Name2'], 
                       values='Size', aggfunc='max', dropna=False)\
                       .rename_axis([None, None], axis="columns")    
print(pvtdf)
#      ABC             BCA         DAB          
#      XCZ   XYZ ZXM   XCZ XYZ ZXM XCZ XYZ   ZXM
# S.No                                          
# 1    NaN  12.0 NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN
# 2    NaN   NaN NaN  15.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN
# 3    NaN   NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.unstack` also to get the desired multiindex format.

Let's say `df` is your data frame. Do this:

```
df = df.set_index(['S.No','Name1','Name2'])['Size'].unstack(level=-2).unstack(level=-1)
df.columns.names = [None, None]
df = df.reindex(columns=['XYZ', 'XCZ', 'ZXM'], level = 1)
df.fillna('', inplace=True) # if you want to replace NAs with blanks

print(df)

       ABC          BCA          DAB
       XYZ XCZ ZXM  XYZ XCZ ZXM  XYZ XCZ ZXM
S.No                                    
1      12                           
2                       15                  
3                                        20
```